# How to change the default page APEX loads

Tags: oracle-apex

I have installed a few instances of APEX using either ORDS or OHS + mod_plsql. Once things have been configured, if a user tries to go to http://< hostname >/apex it gets re-directed to the App Builder login page (http://< hostname >/apex/f?p=4550:1:< session id >:::::).

Is it possible to remove this re-direction, or change it so it goes to a custom html page?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mod_plsql add the following lines to the bottom of the dads.conf

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/pls/apex/$ https:/// [R=301]